# Show product on main page by id opencart

Tags: php, database, opencart

I need to show one certain product on front page. I didn't find a module for this. What do I need to do? I need to show product with countdown timer but I can do this, I only do not know how to get product from database by ID or SKU. I guess the code should be like this:

```
echo $product_option_data[] = array(
                    'product_option_id' => $product_option['product_option_id'],
                    'option_id'         => $product_option['option_id'],
                    'name'              => $product_option['name'],
                    'type'              => $product_option['type'],
                    'option_value'      => $product_option['option_value'],
                    'required'          => $product_option['required']
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCart controller you can call

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product'); // only if not yet 'loaded' within the controller
$product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($productId);
print_r($product);
```

which will return you the product by it's ID. Do with it whatever you need afterwards.

Comment: thank's but one more question - it's show very big array, how can i reduce it for name and show photo?

Comment: The *very big array* contains all the product details (only from `product` table), that's why it's *big* (not that *very big* though). Reducing it is out of the scope of your original question (feel free to ask new one). To show the product's image, take a look into `catalog/controller/product/` folder and open up either of `category.php`, `search.php`, `product.php` (to name few) and search for `image` or `thumb` - this is how the image is prepared. Then look to their corresponding templates to see how it is output (rendered).

Comment: thank you, i did like this   <div class="timer"> <?$this->load->model('catalog/product'); // only if not yet 'loaded' within the controller
$product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct(43);
//print_r($product);?>
<?
$n = 19;
$u = substr($product['image'], 0 , $n);
  //hello w
?>
<span class="name"> <?= $product['name']; ?> </span><br>
<span class="name"> <?=$product['manufacturer']; ?> </span><br>

<img src="http://test1.ru/opencart/image/cache/<? print $u; ?>-200x200.jpg" alt="альтернативный текст"><br>
<span class="name"> <?= $product['price']; ?> </span><br>